# css first-of-type under other class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html file looking something like this:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <h1>gets styled and that's good</h1>
    <h1>doesn't get styled and this is intended</h1>
    <div class="my_other_class">
        <h1>but this also get styled, but shouldn't</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="my_class">
    <h1>do style</h1>
    <h1>don't style</h1>
    <div class="my_other_class">
        <h1>shouldn't but does</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

now I use `.my_class h1:first-of-type {...}` to style the first `h1`. However, the third also gets the style and shouldn't.

Is there a way to only select the first `h1`?

Comment: Is it ever possible for the first `h1` to be within another element similar to the third?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors): `>`:

```
.my_class > h1:first-of-type {...}
```

```css
.my_class > h1:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class">
  <h1>gets styled and that's good</h1>
  <h1>doesn't get styled and this is intended</h1>
  <div class="my_other_class">
    <h1>but this also get styled, but shouldn't</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my_class">
  <h1>do style</h1>
  <h1>don't style</h1>
  <div class="my_other_class">
    <h1>shouldn't but does</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use child combinator `>`.

```css
.my_class > h1:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class">
  <h1>gets styled and that's good</h1>
  <h1>doesn't get styled and this is intended</h1>
  <div class="my_other_class">
    <h1>but this also get styled, but shouldn't</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast and perfect answer!

Comment: @TheOddler - No worries! :)

Answer (score 1):

take the answer from chipChocolate.py. But for the sake of completeness have a look on this:

```
    div, p  Selects all <div> elements and all <p> elements 
    div p   Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements  
    div > p Selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've been learning so much about css the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `:first-child` pseudo element:

```css
.my_class > h1:first-child {
    color: red;
}
p {
    font-size:2em;
}
div div {
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<p>Main Div 1</p>
<div class="my_class">
  <h1>gets styled and that's good</h1>
  <h1>doesn't get styled and this is intended</h1>
  <p>Sub Div 1</p>
  <div class="my_other_class">
    <h1>but this also get styled, but shouldn't</h1>
  </div>
</div>
    <p>Main Div 2</p>
<div class="my_class">
    <h1>do style</h1>
    <h1>don't style</h1>
    <div class="my_other_class">
      <h1>shouldn't but does</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```